# Grouping models in template

Tags: django, django-models

I have two related models:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ptype = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Extra(models.Model):
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package, related_name='package')
    data = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    information = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True)
```

view.py:

```
def show_package(request):
    list = get_list_or_404(Package, ptype='sometype')
    return render(request, 'table.html', {'list': list})
```

and template:

```
{% for row in list %}
<table class="provider_list">
 <tr>
     <td>{{ row.package_name}}</td>
     <td>{{ row.ptype }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I add an additional table (from Extra model) next to the prelated table?

Like:

```
<table>
{% for extra_row in extra_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ extra_row.data }}</td>
    <td>{{ extra_row.information }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Thanks.

Comment: add another table near the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
{% for package in list %}
    <table class="provider_list">
        <tr>
             <td>{{ package.package_name}}</td>
             <td>{{ package.ptype }}</td>
             <td>
                <!-- fetch the related data -->
                <table>
                {% for extra in package.extra_set.all %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ extra.data }}</td>
                        <td>{{ extra.information }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </table>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This means for a resultset of 1000 items, 1000 new queries on the database. Each `package.exra_set.all` is a new query.

Answer (score 1):

You show modify your Extra related_name on package ForeignKey.

models.py

```
class Extra(models.Model):
    extra = models.ForeignKey(Package,related_name='extra_related_name') #default for related_name would be 'extra_set'
```

You can access all extra fields via:

extras = list.extra_related_name.all()

Let's imagine you have only one extra existing on every Package model

views.py

```
def show_package(request):
    list = get_list_or_404(Package, ptype='sometype')
    list.extra = list.extra_related_name.all()[0]
    return render(request, 'table.html', {'list': list})
```

template

```
{% for row in list %}
<table class="provider_list">
 <tr>
    <td>{{ row.package_name}}</td>
    <td>{{ row.ptype }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.extra.data }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.extra.information }}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

If you are sure that there is at most one extra per package you should look at [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) for easier access. If you are unsure, stick to ForeignKey and add checks in the view to check that you are accessing valid data.